# Notepad++ regex to find/ replace at end of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with hundreds of lines ending like:

> [some text] — 1930

That's arbitrary text, then "space dash space", followed by a four-digit year.

The catch is that the arbitrary text sometimes also incudes "space dash space [number]".

I want to replace the final dash with a hash symbol, but not any others on the line.

In other words:

> lorem ipsum 24: 1978 — 1981 — 1922
>
> lorem ipsum 61: 1954 — 1956 foorbar — 1929

would become:

> lorem ipsum 24: 1978 — 1981 # 1922
>
> lorem ipsum 61: 1954 — 1956 foobar # 1929

I've searched Stackoverflow, and the WWW, but can't find a solution.

How can I do this?

UPDATE: Thanks to everyone for the answers; no thanks to the down-voters.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `—( \d+)$`
- Replace with: `#$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
—       : literally  —
( \d+)  : group 1, a space followed by 1 or more digits
$       : end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
lorem ipsum 24: 1978 — 1981 # 1922
lorem ipsum 61: 1954 — 1956 foobar # 1929
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try replacing `-( \d{4})$` by `#$1`

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/o3kDTp/1)

```
—(?= \d{4}$)
```

Replacement: `#`
Uses `gm` flags (global and multiline)

#### Usage

[image: Notepad++ usage]

---

### Results

#### Input

```
lorem ipsum 24: 1978 — 1981 — 1922
lorem ipsum 61: 1954 — 1956 foorbar — 1929
```

#### Output

```
lorem ipsum 24: 1978 — 1981 # 1922
lorem ipsum 61: 1954 — 1956 foorbar # 1929
```

---

### Explanation

- `—` Match this literally
- `(?= \d{4}$)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a space, followed by exactly 4 digits, followed by the end of the line (`$` is end of line assertion)